# Problems in dependency/reference setup within a solution (assembly not found / file not found)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependency-management, .net-5

I have problems setting up my dependencies within a solution.

The following solution structure:

- LibraryProjectA (.netstandard 2.0) has a NuGet reference to "system.componentmodel.annotations" /
- LibraryProjectB (.netstandard 2.0) references LibraryProjectA
- ConsoleProject (.NET Framework 4.8) references LibraryProjectA and LibraryProjectB

LibraryProjectA has this base class:

```
    public abstract class FooConverterBase<T> : IFooConverter<T> {
        public T Convert(object input) {
            var result = DoConvert(input);
            ValidateResult(result);
            return result;
        }

        protected abstract T DoConvert(object input);

        private void ValidateResult(T result) {
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(result);
            Validator.ValidateObject(result, validationContext, true);
        }
     }
```

LibraryB extends that base class `public class BarConverter : FooConverterBase<MyObject>` but when I try to use `BarConverter` within the ConsoleProject I get an assembly not found / file not found exception. I resolve this issue when I install "system.componentmodel.annotations" directly as a NuGet package to my ConsoleProject.

How do I have to setup my dependecies or LibraryProjectA.csproj file that I won't have to manually install that package to my ConsoleProject?

---

Current LibraryProjectA.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Auto</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Do you have the same target framework version for each projects?

Comment: How does LibraryProjectA  `csproj` file look like?

Comment: i updated the target framework versions of the projects and added the LibraryProjectA `csproj`